# Compare class for std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++11

I know this has been asked and answered several times over Stack Overflow and I have been through all the answers and tried them out but none of them seem to work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct twoInt{
    int a;
    int b;
    twoInt(int x, int y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
};

struct classcomp{
    bool operator() (twoInt* lhs, twoInt* rhs)
    {return lhs->a < rhs->a;}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<twoInt*> v;
    v.push_back(new twoInt(1,1));
    v.push_back(new twoInt(8,8));
    v.push_back(new twoInt(8,8));
    v.push_back(new twoInt(9,9));
    twoInt* temp = new twoInt(7,7);
    std::vector<twoInt*>::iterator low;
    // low=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), temp, classcomp());
    // low=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), temp, std::bind2nd(std::less<twoInt*>(), classcomp));
    // low=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), temp, [](twoInt* lhs, twoInt* rhs) -> bool { return lhs->a < rhs->a; });
    std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low-v.begin()) << '\n';
}
```

The three lines in the main that are commented out in the main are all the approaches I have tried out based on the answers from Stack Overflow and I get different errors.

Comment: First and third [compile for me just fine](http://rextester.com/DOGCVI35394); the second is plain nonsense. What are those "different errors" you are getting?

Comment: You need to `#include <algorithm>`, then the first commented line will work.

Comment: Incidentally, you are leaking all those objects. As they are, they probably just shouldn't be allocated with `new` - just use a vector of values, not of pointers (and change your `push_back` accordingly).

Comment: Do you *have* to use pointers? Because it can be done much easier without. And what's your question?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This code compiled fine on my mac but did not on a Linux environment.
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:943:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
sam.cpp:26:63: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
     low=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), temp, classcomp());

Comment: @Praetorian this worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @rustyx This is a simplified example of a more complicated code I was working on.

Answer (score 3):

**The question was edited. Bellow is answer before edit.**

1. The problem consists of storing pointers and using references in the comparer: the vector contains pointers to `twoInt` and `classcomp` must work with pointers too. See the manual to `std::lower_bound` (`std::vector<twoInt*>::type` is `twoInt*` --> `T` is `twoInt*`).
2. Another error: the third argument of `std::lower_bound` must be pointer too (`T`), but you pass int.

I suggest you not using pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct twoInt{
    int a;
    int b;
    twoInt(int x, int y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }

    bool operator < (const twoInt& rhs) {
        return a < rhs.a;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<twoInt> v;
    v.push_back(twoInt(1,1));
    v.push_back(twoInt(8,8));
    v.push_back(twoInt(8,8));
    v.push_back(twoInt(9,9));
    std::vector<twoInt>::iterator low;
    low=std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), twoInt(9, 0));
    std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low-v.begin()) << '\n';
}
```